# FrameLayout to RelativeLayout ClassCastException even if there is no FrameLayout used

Tags: android, android-layout, classcastexception, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

In my application, I have a layout which has a `RelativeLayout` to which I want to set margins at runtime programmatically. But when I do that, it gives me `ClassCastException` saying `FrameLayout` can not cast to `RelativeLayout`. I don't have any FrameLayout used, also there are no imports for `FrameLayout`. Still the problem persists. The xml I am using is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_root"
android:background="@color/menu_bg"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_lhs_menu"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/menu_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    .....

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/capture_port"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    ....

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my onCreate where I set the margins to the parent layout:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.menu);

 _rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_root);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _rootLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(_rootLayout.getWidth(), _rootLayout.getHeight());
_rootLayoutParams.setMargins(300, 0, 300, 0);
_rootLayout.setLayoutParams(_rootLayoutParams);
}
```

And here is the LogCat:

```
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:268)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:764)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4355)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:1912)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10828)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:960)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2062)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4128)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    07-18 21:12:39.410: E/AndroidRuntime(7663):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try setting FrameLayout.LayoutParams instead if RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. When you set the layout params at runtime, you have to set the ones from it's parent.

So, it'll be:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams _rootLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(_rootLayout.getWidth(), _rootLayout.getHeight());
_rootLayoutParams.setMargins(300, 0, 300, 0);
_rootLayout.setLayoutParams(_rootLayoutParams);
```

Comment: Nope. `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` does not have any `setMargins()` method. And if I cast it to `MarginLayoutParams` again a different classCastException occurs.

Comment: Have you tried FrameLayout.LayoutParams? Due to your logCat error, that could be the correct one. See my edit.

Comment: Hey, `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` removed that ClassCastException but its not showing any UI then.

Comment: Youl'll have to check how _rootLayoutParams is initialized, then. It seems that you're setting the width and height of _rootLayout, but I don't see that object in your code.

Comment: Yes, its just before that code
`_rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_root);`
forgot to put that in the question. Updated.

But why is it asking for `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`?

Comment: If you're debugging in a handset, you're not seeing nothing because you're setting 300px margin int the left side and 300px in the right side, thus all your content is collapsed.

Comment: No Sir, can we please [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14085/discussion-between-rajkiran-and-chinaski)??

Answer (score 2):

I've had this error once before and it was because I tried to cast the parameters instead of creating a new instance.  I hope this helps.

Right here :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _rootLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(_rootLayout.getWidth(), _rootLayout.getHeight());
```

Should be:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _rootLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(_rootLayout.getLayoutParams());
```

Now that you have all the layout parameters from the parent (root) layout, you can use them to set the parameters for your child view that you are inflating.

```
// Example usage:   
// viewGroup is the parent in this case whose parameters we want as a reference point.
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(viewGroup.getLayoutParams());

// Now we can add a rule stating that we want to center our new view both horizontally and vertically in the parent (viewGroup) view.
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

// Add more rules here if you would like
params.addRule(newRule2);

// After all of your new parameters are laid out, assign them to the view you want them applied to  
newView.setLayoutParams(params);

// Add the view to your hierarchy and enjoy
viewGroup.addView(newView);
```

Comment: What is viewGroup here?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the parent of the @id/rl_root must be FrameLayout which is not showing in this xml. LayoutParam's type should be the same with its parent not itself.