# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout, android-contentprovider, classcastexception, android-relativelayout

Here I need to add textview at runtime. first I took reference of RelativeLayout to get layout params but unfortunately its throwing ClassCastException at **RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)contentLayout.getLayoutParams()**

I also checked - [FrameLayout to RelativeLayout ClassCastException even if there is no FrameLayout used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544964/framelayout-to-relativelayout-classcastexception-even-if-there-is-no-framelayout), but it didn't work. Since after replacing RelativeLayout with FrameLayout, I'm unable to add rule on layoutParams.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            TextView displayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display_text);

            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = resolver.query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            displayTextView.setText("The User Dictionary contains " + cursor.getColumnCount() + " words");

            RelativeLayout contentLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_layout);

            TextView columnNames = new TextView(this);
            columnNames.setText("Columns: _id - frequency - word");
            contentLayout.addView(columnNames);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)contentLayout.getLayoutParams();
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);

            do{
                TextView entry = new TextView(this);
                entry.setText(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserDictionary.Words._ID)) + " - " +
                              cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserDictionary.Words.FREQUENCY)) + " - " +
                              cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserDictionary.Words.WORD)));

                entry.setLayoutParams(params);
                contentLayout.addView(entry);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());

            cursor.close();
    }

    **Getting following error** - 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dexter.contentpro/com.example.dexter.contentpro.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
                at com.example.dexter.contentpro.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

activity_main.xml-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As per your code everything looks fine. Delete R.java and recompile it and run again. You should use Relative Layout not Frame layout ideally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Error is right and you are also right,but its a misinterpretation on both you and android's part.  You see when you `Inflate` a `View` with `Parent_View` being any sub class of a `ViewGroup`, android returns that `View` and treat it like a `View` if you want to treat it like a subclass of a `ViewGroup` you are going to have some cast Excetpions... *You see i know this by experience but i cant give you a documented fact about this*

Back to your question; you try to get the `Layoutparams` of your `RelativeLayout` which is the top most `View` of that xml, so i am thinking `getLayoutParams()` should return `null` since its not attached to a `ViewGroup` but its not which means its attached to a `FrameLayout` which is the Top most `View` for the `Window` or itself.

**To solve it**

*try this* (1)

instead of using this line

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                          contentLayout.getLayoutParams();
```

use this

```
//get the layoutParams of the TextView child in the Relativelayout in 
//your xml,this will automatically map to the RelativeLayout params
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                          displayTextView.getLayoutParams();
```

*or use this*(2)

change only your xml, and your previous code will work fine

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/content_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/display_text"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```